# Laravel validation does not work

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I used laravel 5.2 to build my app but suddenly validation doesn't work out on registration`new users

```
Route::post('/register','userController@store');
```

my function on validation part for storing users details

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'fname' => 'required|max:50',
        'lname' => 'required|max:50',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'phone' => 'required|unique:users',
        'provider' => 'required',
        'company' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
        'IDtype' => 'required',
        'IDnumber' => 'required',
        'region' => 'required|max:32',
        'signature' => 'required'
    ]);
}
```

Things were working well but now return

```
"fname":["validation.required"],"lname":["validation.required"],"email":["validation.required"],"IDtype":["validation.required"],"IDnumber":["validation.required"]}   returned as response
```

`

Comment: Have u added all fields in your User Model's  fillable method ?

Comment: No I didn't because fillable is just for mass assignment I have been using this method for year now

Answer (score 2):

You shoud use $request->all() instead of $request

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request->all(),[
            ........
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: when I tried to use that I have got this error as response            
 Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in F:\xampp\htdocs\loanclub\app\Http\Controllers\userController.php on line 57 and defined

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.5 you can call the validate method on request and it's recommended

```
$request->validate($rules);
```

Comment: I have got this error BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method validate does not exist.